# Binding multiple rows and columns for WHERE IN clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So I want to prepare a query something like:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE (branch, cid) IN $1;
```

And then bind a variable length set of rows like `(('a','b'),('c','d'))` to it.

In other words, something like:

```
pg_prepare($users, 'users_query', 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE (branch, cid) IN $1');
$result = pg_execute($users, 'users_query', array("(('a','b'),('c','d'))");
```

The reason I need to split the two is because I want to prepare it once and then run it many times with as little overhead as possible.

Comment: @dbenhur It does work. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.3, I can paste output if you want?

Comment: Do you have an index on users(branch,cid) ?  Post the explain analyze plan for your actual query if you can.

Comment: Yep, primary key is (branch, cid). Here's the explain:

Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=8.52..12.54 rows=1 width=8)
  Recheck Cond: (((branch = 'a'::text) AND (cid = 'b'::text)) OR ((branch = 'c'::text) AND (cid = 'd'::text)))
  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.52..8.52 rows=1 width=0)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((branch = 'a'::text) AND (cid = 'b'::text))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((branch = 'c'::text) AND (cid = 'd'::text))
(7 rows)

Comment: You should edit the plan into your question so you can format it nicer.  What's the problem with that plan? It looks very cheap.  Also, use EXPLAIN ANALYZE in preference to EXPLAIN so one can see actual times and row counts.

Comment: I have 2 rows in there so not much use analyze-ing :P  The issue is that I can't work out how to prepare that query and supply the parenthesized subquery by binding. I started playing around with ANY() and row constructors but that led to a sequential scan, rather than the above bitmap heap scan.

Comment: @Alec: If you only have two rows, the query optimizer will probably *always* choose a sequential scan. Think about it for a minute. Then add more rows.

Comment: @Catcall Okay, yes, to be honest I didn't realise the query optimiser took the number of rows into account. But that doesn't answer how I pass the values as a parameter - as in preparing a query with $1 in it and binding the values later. My trials with ANY got as far as `WHERE branch = ANY($1)`, with `{a,c}`, but then I couldn't pass more than 1 column by binding. And I gave up with ANY when I tried `EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM users WHERE (branch, cid) = ANY(ARRAY[('a'::text,'b'::text),('c'::text,'d'::text)]);` and it did a sequential scan.

Comment: @Alec, when I ask for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` it's because that form of EXPLAIN actually runs the query and includes actual times and row counts in the plan, instead of just the estimates you get with normal `EXPLAIN`.  I think the "analyze-ing" you think is unnecessary is `ANALYZE TABLE`. Nevertheless, you should do that anyway whenever you populate a table and want to tune a query for performance.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you get sequential scans with only two records is meaningless. An index will never be faster than seqential scan for such a tiny set.  I built a small sample table akin to yours and populated it with a million rows and the following query style consistently produces nice plans and fast executions:

```sql
prepare s4 as
select id from users
join (select * from (values ($1,$2),($3,$4)) as v(branch, cid)) as p
using (branch, cid);

explain analyze execute s4('b11','c11','b1234','c1234');
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..16.65 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.199..0.234 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=64) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using u_i on users  (cost=0.00..8.30 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.111..0.112 rows=1 loops=2)
         Index Cond: ((users.branch = "*VALUES*".column1) AND (users.cid = "*VALUES*".column2))
 Total runtime: 0.425 ms
```

It seems your real issue is how to bind a dynamically determined number of value pairs to your sql. My PHP is horribly rusty and reading the online docs reminded me how much I loathe it, but I think the following will do what you want, constructing sql of the form above with the number of value pair placeholders dynamically created based on the number of values you wish to bind. I have no php execution environment handy, so I haven't even checked if it's syntactically correct, but you should be able to get the idea and work out any trivial bugs in my example.

```php
$values = array(
  'a', 'b',
  'c', 'd',
  // etc...
);

$value_placeholders = "";
$sep = "";
for ($i=1; $i <= $count($values); $i+=2) {
  $value_placeholders = $value_placeholders . sprintf("($%u,$%u),", $i, $i+1) . $sep
  $sep = ",";
}

$sql =
  'select id from users ' .
  'join (select * from (values ' . $value_placeholders . ') as v(branch, cid)) as p' .
  'using (branch, cid)';

$result = pg_query_params($dbconn, $sql, $values);
```

If you really just must have a single prepared statement (and for a guy who can't be bothered to actually try his queries against a real data set instead of two records, we'll completely avoid the talk about [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)), I think I have an answer for you:

```
create index u_i2 on users ((branch||cid));
prepare sa as select id from users where branch||cid in (select unnest($1::text[]));
explain analyze execute sa(ARRAY['b1c1','b1234c1234']);
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=12.17..645.78 rows=50000 width=4) (actual time=0.169..0.188 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=2 loops=1)
         ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=12.14..638.25 rows=500 width=16) (actual time=0.082..0.082 rows=1 loops=2)
         Recheck Cond: ((users.branch || users.cid) = (unnest($1)))
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on u_i2  (cost=0.00..12.02 rows=500 width=0) (actual time=0.078..0.078 rows=1 loops=2)
               Index Cond: ((users.branch || users.cid) = (unnest($1)))
 Total runtime: 0.275 ms
```

Note:: I could not find away to get indexed access to row-pairs. But if you make a functional index on the concatenation of the two fields, then supply a bound array of such concatenations, you get a nice fast nest-loop-index-scan.

Comment: The problem is that the number of values isn't constant. As I said in the comments above, I can perform a `WHERE branch IN` equivalent with `WHERE branch = ANY($1)` with a parameter like `{'a','c'}`. The problem is I don't know how to do this with multiple columns for an `WHERE (branch, cid) IN` equivalent.

Comment: @Alec I gave you code which sizes the placeholders based on the size of the array of values. What more do you need?  Have you tried the php I posted? I assumed php is your execution environment since you tagged the question with it.

Comment: Yes, PHP's the environment, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to pg_prepare the statement with a placeholder, and then pg_execute it with different value pairs, and different numbers of value pairs. See updated question.

Comment: for a query as simple as this, the planning step is very fast, so you don't really win much from the prepared statement.

Comment: @Alec updated answer with a single-placeholder prepared statement solution that plans well